# HotChocolate sorting on nested collection property

Tags: hotchocolate

Say a user can have a document set which each set can have one or more files. On the UI I want to allow the user to sort by the file CreatedDate.  So when the user clicks on the column header they can sort by date (asc/desc).  Given the following how can I configure this sorting behavior HotChocolate side?

```
public class User 
{
   public List<DocSet> DocSets {get;set;}
}


public class DocSet
{
   public List<File> Files {get;set}
   public User User {get;set;}
}

public File
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public DocSet DocSet {get;set;}
   public DateTime CreatedDate {get;set;}
}
```

Here's the HotChocolate query but not sure how to allow sorting (asc/desc) on the File CreatedDate property.

```
[UseDbContext]
[UseSorting]
public IQueryable<User> GetUser(
    [ScopedService] MyDbContext dbContext
) => dbContext.Users;
```

Comment: Would this example not have a circular reference User -> DocSet -> User -> DocSet?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```cs
public class DocSet
{
   [UseSorting]
   public List<File> Files {get;set}
   public User User {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me

Comment: This doesnt work for me either

Comment: The resolver that return DocSet must use [UseProjection]